# Mysql, repeat row by the max count of details

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I have two tables
Master table

```
|-----------|--------|------------|
| id_client | name   | ci         |
|-----------|--------|------------|
|    1      | B      |     123    |
|    2      | A      |     234    |
|    3      | C      |     345    |
|-----------|--------|------------|
```

Detail of equipments

```
|-----------|--------------|
| id_client | id_equipment | 
|-----------|--------------|
|    1      | 1            |    
|    1      | 2            |     
|    2      | 3            |     
|-----------|--------------|
```

The result that I expected is:
All clientes with or without equipments

```
|-----------|----------------|----------------|
| id_client | id_equipment   | numberEquipment|
|-----------|----------------|----------------|
|    1      | 1              |     Equip1     |
|    1      | 2              |     Equip2     |
|    2      | 3              |     Equip1     |
|    2      | -              |     Equip2     |
|    3      | -              |     Equip1     |
|    3      | -              |     Equip2     |
|-----------|----------------|----------------|
```

Client 1 have two equipments and this is the max cant of equipments assigned, then, all clientes with minor than two have to fill the detail empty two times. client 2 have one equipment assigned, the second will be empty, and cliente 3 doesnt have any equipment, then the two equipments will be empty.

I was implemented crosstab on jasperreport, i have to define de columnGroup, when the name of group Equipment1, equipment2... etc, doesnt exist on any row this column group doesnt show.

I hope someone can helpme.
Thanks.

```
SELECT CONCAT('EQUIPMENT ',g.ennum) AS numberEquipment,
g.ID_CLIENTE as id_client, g.ID_EQUIPO as id_equipment,
(SELECT @running1:= 0) AS running1,(SELECT @previous1:= 0) AS previous1
FROM (
SELECT c.ID_CLIENTE, eq.ID_EQUIPO
@running1:=if(@previous1=concat(eq.ID_CLIENTE),@running1,0) + 1 as ennum, @previous1:=concat(eq.ID_CLIENTE) 
FROM CLIENTE AS c
LEFT JOIN detail_equipments AS eq ON eq.ID_CLIENTE = c.ID_CLIENTE
ORDER BY c.ID_CLIENTE ) AS g
GROUP BY g.ID_CLIENTE, g.ID_EQUIPO
ORDER BY ID_CLIENTE, g.ennum
```

this show

|-----------|----------------|----------------|
| id_client | id_equipment   | numberEquipment|
|-----------|----------------|----------------|
|    1      | 1              |     Equip1     |
|    1      | 2              |     Equip2     |
|    2      | 3              |     Equip1     |
|    3      | -              |     Equip1     |
|-----------|----------------|----------------|

Comment: What is `numberEquipment`?

Comment: Where's your query?

Comment: I  hope in the query create this data for show the amount of equipments, I need a value to increase from one to the maximum of equipments assigneds in this case two, for each cliente, i have to show, equipment1, equipment2.